# number of other company count

Tags: sql

```
Table
Director    DirectorId  Company     CompanyID   Recordtime
Philip            66    AVEVA GROUP     15         1
Philip            66    AVEVA GROUP     15         1
Philip            66    BALFOUR BEATTY  36         1
Philip            66    BHP BILLITON    40         2
Philip            66    BHP BILLITON    40         2
```

```
 OutPut like this
Director    DirectorId  Company     CompanyID   Count
Philip            66    AVEVA GROUP     15         1
Philip            66    AVEVA GROUP     15         1
Philip            66    BALFOUR BEATTY  36         1
Philip            66    BHP BILLITON    40         0
Philip            66    BHP BILLITON    40         0
```

in this table recordtime 1 has two company and recordtime 2  has one
company .i need output of count 1 in  recordtime 1 count 0 in recordtime 2 because 
recordtime 1 the first company is default company after all is countable this is condition

Comment: what about count is it empty if not show the output

Comment: one company is default it not include as count more than one is include as count

Comment: basedon recordtime there is only 1 company means count as 0 .Two companies means count as 1 .three means count as 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
select t1.*, t2.cCount from Table1 t1 join 
(select Recordtime, (count(CompanyId) - 1) as cCount from (select distinct CompanyID, Recordtime from Table1) t
group by Recordtime) t2 on t1.Recordtime = t2.Recordtime
```

Take a look at this [sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee77e/8)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case:

```
SELECT v.director,
       v.directorId,
       v.company,
       v.companyId,
       CASE WHEN v.cnt > 1 THEN v.cnt - 1
            ELSE 0 END AS cnt
FROM (SELECT t.director,
             t.directorId,
             t.company,
             t.companyId,
             COUNT(DISTINCT t.company) as cnt
      FROM yourtable t
      GROUP BY t.director,
               t.directorId,
               t.company,
               t.companyId) v
```

Comment: i think your query will simply eliminate all the duplicates in the table, so instead of 5 rows as output, you will only get 3. Also your grouping will return counts for each distinct row, meaning that the count will always be 1(but you will see the output with -1) and the output will be 0

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why subquery should contain PK-column in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses. I just don't now the name of PK-column

Comment: Even if you would know the primary key, to use it in your query you will need to add it in the group by clause, so you will not resolve the other problem with the count results.

Comment: If author's database is Oracle, he could use something like this:
`COUNT(DISTINCT t.company) OVER (PARTITION BY t.recordtime)`
without `GROUP BY` clause at all.